# How to structure complex "state updating functions" in Clojure?

Tags: design-patterns, clojure, functional-programming

I have a game state represented as a map and some logic that updates that state on every game 'tic'. But I can't figure out how to structure the update function in any sane way.

What is the idiomatic pattern for structuring functions like this?

Here is some pseudo code for what I want to do:

```
(defn tic [g] "Return an updated game"
  g1 = (update-in g [:day] inc)
  g2 = (if (some-cond) (some-update-func g1) g1)
  g3 = (update-in g2 [:fu] fu-update)
  ... many more ...
  g-last)
```

I don't really care about the intermediate states, but using the -> macro doesn't work (since there are some conditionals).

A hack that works is using a local atom that is reset! for every 'line' in the update function. But that can't be how it's supposed to be done?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to extract each of the steps in a nicely named function, so that you can use ->. Pseudo code:

```
(defn tic [g]
    (-> g
        inc-day
        random-weather
        grow-trees
        ...))
```

For any conditional logic, you can just do something similar to what you do in your g2 step.

Perhaps you will find [synthread lib](https://github.com/LonoCloud/synthread) useful. I found [this video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Macros-Monads) very instructive.

Look also at [cond->](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/cond_DASH__GT/) to see how could you mix -> with some cond. For example your cond could look like:

```
(cond-> g
        true (update-in [:day] inc)
        (some-cond) some-update-fund
        true (update-in [:fu] fu-update))
```

Comment: A combination of named functions, for logical blocks, and the synthread lib looks like a nice solution. It has macros similar to the 'mabey' macro described in the other answer (and many more).

Answer (score 3):

You can still use `->` if for the conditional steps, you wrap the operation in an anonymous function.

```
(-> g0 
    ...
    (#(if (some-cond) (u %) %))
    ...)
```

If you are concerned about efficiency (you mentioned this is a game) I would recommend you  use `cond->` or maybe create your own macro. `cond->` requires repeating `true` for expressions that are always threaded, which may be tedious, depending on the number of items in your thread.

Here is a macro that can be used in conjuction with `->` that avoids excessive creation of anonymous functions and avoids the repetitiveness of `cond->`:

```
(defmacro maybe [val sym cond expr]
  `(let [~sym ~val] (if ~cond ~expr ~sym)))
```

It can be used like this:

```
(-> g0
    ...
    (maybe gn (some-cond gn) (updater gn))
    ...)
```

If you don't need to use the partially-processed value `gn` in the condition expression, you can just use `cond->` instead of `maybe`:

```
(-> g0
    ...
    (cond-> (some-cond g0) updater)
    ...)
```

Another example:

```
(-> 10 (maybe gn (= gn 10) (* gn 100)))
```

Which evaluates to `1000`

Comment: You should have a look at `cond->`, I believe it would replace `maybe` nicely.

Comment: @omiel `cond->` is definitely an option, so I edited my answer accordingly. But it looks nasty if most of your conditions are `true` and doesn't work if you want to use the current value in the condition.
I edited my answer to make the `maybe` macro actually useful - before it was just moving the anonymous function creating problem around rather than solving it.

Comment: You misunderstand: I was suggesting that you nest a `cond->` form inside a `->` one, not that you use `cond->` exclusively.

Comment: @omiel Correct, although there are cases where maybe is more powerful. Added an extra example.